# TortoiseHg Workbench: where, oh where, is the revision history view?

Tags: tortoisehg

OK, this is stupid, but I cannot for the life of me find the revision history view in TortoiseHg Workbench. It was there and then it was gone.

It lists each revision and then it is possible to click on a particular revision, causing a list of all the files (of that revision) to appear in a left column window.

I feel like I have tried every button and menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default WorkBench view

[image: WorkBench]

If you have some panes hidden (collapsed?) you have to find border and drag&drop it in the right direction (sorry, I can't show cursor on screenshots).

Comment: I think maybe it has popped out of the main window altogether. When I open the workbench, there is a tiny window that appears for a brief instant before the main window appears. Hmm..

Comment: Yes, finally! You're right. It was collapsed. I had to drag down, from between the toolbar and the main window. Of course, now the file view opens in a separate window, sigh.

Comment: @user984003 This was my problem as well. Feeling stupid :-D